# @Query result type different between ImpermanentGraphDatabase and SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase?

Tags: neo4j, spring-data-neo4j

I am using the @Query annotation on a repository interface method to retrieve a list of nodes contained in a path.

If I switch from the ImpermanentGraphDatabase to the SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase, I am having errors while parsing the results because the type returned by the query is very different :

**Context** :

- Using SDN 3.3.0.RELEASE and Neo4j 2.1.7
- Code is used in a Junit test
- My graph is like this : `(t:Type1)-[:HAS_KEY]->(:Key)-[:NEXT]->(:Key)-[:NEXT]->(:Key)-[:NEXT]->`.... and so on (Yeah, it sounds like a LinkedList ^^)
- The query is "I want all the keys associated to my type" so I used a path query :

  `MATCH (key:Key)<-[:HAS_KEY]-(:Type1 {typeId :{0}}), p=(key)-[:NEXT*]->(:Key)
  RETURN nodes(p)
  ORDER BY length(p) desc
  LIMIT 1`

**Using ImpermanentGraphDatabase :**

- My query returns `Iterable<Iterable<Object>>` and I have to cast the "Object" inside to my NodeEntity using `Neo4jOperations.convert(...)` method because those objects are of type `NodeProxy`.

**Using SpringCypherRestGraphDatabase :**

- My query returns `Iterable<Iterable<Map<String, String>>>`, and the map contains the property name of the node as key and the corresponding value as the map entry value.

Why is there such implementation difference ? Shouldn't we expect the same behaviour regardless of the database service implementation ?

Thank you.

**P.S.** : By the way, I tried to achieve the same goal using a TraversalDescription: it works and the same TraversalDescription works on both database implementations

Comment: If you're 100% sure both DBs are in 2.1.7: are you sure they contain the same data? If not, what's the difference?

Comment: Yes, both are in 2.1.7 and yes they contains the same data. In fact I run the same unit test, first with the ImpermanentGraphDatabase and then with the REST one. Same data, same code executed but result type different when using the @query on the rest server.

Comment: By the way, I have also tried an other query which return a collect() of node. I tried to map this with a @QueryResult and a field of type List<MyNode>, it works with impermanentDatabase, but still, with the REST one it fail on type conversion because he gets a List<LinkedHashMap<String, String>> and not a list of MyNode. Why can't SDN convert the map to the appropriate entity i m trying to obtain ?